# jQuery unbind('hover') does not work

Tags: jquery, unbind

My unbind does not work.

```
$("img.hoverable").hover(ChangeImage, ChangeBack);
$("a img.hoverable").unbind('hover');
```

The HTML could be like this

```
<img class="hoverable" src="something.jpg"/>
<a href="#"><img class="hoverable" src="something.jpg"/></a>
```

When I hover over the second HTML, ChangeImage is still fired.

I am not sure if I am using it correctly, can anyone please advise?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try

```
$("img.hoverable").unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
```

The .hover() method binds handlers for both mouseenter and mouseleave events. So inorder to unbind you will have to unbind mouseenter and mouseleave.

Comment: This doesn't work when I try it

Answer (score 5):

`hover` is a pseudo event for `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`. So you have to unbind these.
Or if no other handler is attached, call `.unbind()` without parameters (removes any handler).

```
$("a img.hoverable").unbind();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("img.hoverable").hover(ChangeImage, ChangeBack);
$("img.hoverable").unbind('hover');
```

Answer (score 0):

.hover is a wrapper for mouseenter and mouseleave.

Try calling unbind on those.